# Phonegap load plugins from remote js

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a mobile-optimized web app that I would like to package in a Phonegap app.

The easiest way to do that would be to call `window.open(SERVER_URL, "_self")` right after `deviceready` fires, and include in this remote HTML the phonegap.js lib. In other words, to just use phonegap as a dumb display for my server-rendered content.

While this works for almost all of it, I do need to use the InAppBrowser plugin to be able to open some links in Safari via `window.open(URL, "_system")`; also, in the future I will need to use notifications.

My problem is that including a script tag with phonegap.js in a remote-loaded html doesn't seem to work for loading plugins.

My question is: how do I add plugins to the Phonegap webview from a remote-loaded html?